# Union of half-open interval

Tags: measure-theory

Is it possible to say that for a half open interval
$\ \ \ (a_1,a_k], k\in\mathbb N$ such that it can be divided into finite union of disjoint half open interval$\ \ \ {(a_i,a_{i+1}]}\ \forall 1\le i\le k-1$,i.e. $(a_1,a_k] = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1} (a_i,a_{i+1}]$?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? $(a_1, a_k]$ is already a finite union of disjoint half-open intervals. And of course if $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_{k-1} < a_k$ then we have $(a_1, a_k] = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}(a_i, a_{i+1}]$.

Comment: I mean is it possible for $(a_1,a_k] = (a_1,a_2]\bigcup(a_2,a_3]...\bigcup(a_{k-1},a_k]$?

Comment: Of course it is possible. For example, $(0, 3] = (0, 1]\cup (1, 2]\cup(2, 3]$.